# Получить из объекта все объекты, которые ссылаются на него

Tags: c#, .net

Вопрос интереса ради:

CLR удаляет объекты на основании отсутствия корневых ссылок => он владеет информацией о ссылках между объектами.

Теперь собственно сам вопрос:

Допустим есть 2 объекта.

1 Объект содержит поле, которое ссылается на объект 2.

Можно ли имея на руках второй объект понять, что на него что-то ссылается и получить эту ссылку?

Comment: он скорее владеет информацией о количестве ссылок, а не о том, кто именно ссылается

Comment: вам надо 'всего лишь' повторить механизм обхода графа ссылок, тогда ваш вопрос сведется к поиску ребра в графе с концом в вашем объекте

Comment: @teran Рихтер писал, что это неэффективно и не выявляет циклические ссылки => Майрософт реализовали другой механизм.

Comment: @iluxa1810 оки, будем знать, однако это может быть достаточно затратно по памяти. Но вообще да, для автоматической сборки мусора обычный неуправляемый подход не пойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, этой информации нет, т. к. объект знает только свои ссылки на другие объекты. Вы можете её получить, но это сложно.

Смотрите, что делает сборщик мусора. Он знает все *корневые* объекты. Это статические объекты, а также объекты, ссылки на которые есть в стеке какого-либо из потоков.* Он считает их достижимыми, не подлежащими удалению. Затем, он проходит по ссылкам из уже найденных достижимых объектов, найденные объекты тоже объявляет достижимыми. Затем он обходит вновь определённые достижимые объекты, проходит по их ссылкам, и найденные объекты тоже объявляет достижимыми.

Таким образом, обходя достижимые объекты, сборщик мусора рано или поздно натыкается на ссылку, ведущую из первого объекта во второй. Или не натыкается, если первый объект не достижим.

---

Повторять этот алгоритм большого смысла нет, т. к. это просто медленно. (И у нас в руках лишь довольно медленная рефлексия.)

Проблему, которая у вас на руках, нужно решать по-другому. Например, заставлять объекты, которым нужен ваш объект №2, регистрироваться самостоятельно.

---

*ну и объекты, на которые ссылаются всякие `GCHandle`'ы